# tree table using normal html tree table- angular 2+

Tags: angular, angular6, angular5, angular7

I am trying for a tree table using normal html table.

```
{
"policy": [
    {
        "id": "a1",
        "name": "policy 1.1",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "c1",
                "name": "category 1.1",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "s1",
                        "name": "subCategory 1.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "s2",
                        "name": "subCategory 1.2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "c2",
                "name": "category 1.2",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "s5",
                        "name": "subCategory 2.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "s6",
                        "name": "subCategory 2.2"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": "a2",
        "name": "policy 1.2",
        "categories": [
            {
                "id": "c4",
                "name": "category 1.1",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "s13",
                        "name": "subCategory 1.1"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "c5",
                "name": "category 1.2",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "s17",
                        "name": "subCategory 2.1"
                    },
                    {
                        "id": "s18",
                        "name": "subCategory 2.2"
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "id": "c6",
                "name": "category 1.3",
                "subCategories": [
                    {
                        "id": "s21",
                        "name": "subCategory 3.1"
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
   ]
  }
```

I dont want to use any library.

ts file:

```
  getAllAuditPolicies() {
    this.policyService
     .getAllPolicies()
     .subscribe(data => {
       this.dropdownData = data;
   });
 }
```

to open the category

```
 open(i){
   this.dropdownData1 = this.dropdownData[i].categories;
   console.log("dataas1", this.dropdownData1);
 }
```

to open the subcategory

```
subOpen(j){
   this.dropdownData2 = this.dropdownData1[j].subCategories;
   console.log("dataas2", this.dropdownData2);
 }
```

HTML file:

```
     <div class="container">
      <div class="row">
       <table class="table">
        <tr class="panel-heading bgOrg">
          <th class="th-font">&nbsp;</th>
          <th class="th-font">Name</th>
       </tr>
      <tr *ngFor='let data of dropdownData; let i=index' (click)="open(i)" >
          <td >+</td>
          <td>{{data.name}}</td>        
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor='let group of dropdownData1; let j=index' (click)="subOpen(j)">
        <td>+</td>
        <td>{{group.name}}</td>     
      </tr>
      <tr *ngFor='let subgroup of dropdownData2; let k=index' >
        <td>+</td>
        <td>{{subgroup.name}}</td>     
      </tr >
      <tr></tr>
    </table>
  </div>
</div>
```

Using this method, the table is showing details.

**Problem**:

but,The categories of policy1.1 is category1.1 and category1.2.it should show below the policy1.1 as nested. But if I click on policy1.1,Table is showing values below policy1.2(Expanding the values of policy1.1 below all policies).

Same problem is affecting for subcategories
For reference stackblitz implementation is attaching,

[stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19bfsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

What I want to do for solving this problem.

Can  anybody help me??

Thanks in Advance

Comment: Can you provide example implementation in stackblitz

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-19bfsa?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

Comment: here is the stackblitz example...

Comment: hi @AngelReji, i have developed an angular plugin `angular-tree-table` for this,  here is the demo https://anjnkmr.github.io/angular-tree-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check if this will work for you

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gxeins?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html

```html
<table class="table">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th>Id</th>
            <th>Name</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <ng-container *ngFor='let policy of data.policy'>
            <tr>
                <td (click)="policy.expand=!policy.expand">+</td>
                <td>{{policy.id}}</td>
                <td>{{policy.name}}</td>
            </tr>
            <ng-container *ngIf="policy.expand && policy.categories && policy.categories.length>0">
                <ng-container *ngFor='let category of policy.categories'>
                    <tr>
                        <td></td>
                        <td (click)="category.expand=!category.expand"> +</td>
                        <td>{{category.id}}</td>
                        <td>{{category.name}}</td>
                    </tr>
                    <ng-container *ngIf="category.expand && category.subCategories && category.subCategories.length>0">
                        <ng-container *ngFor='let subcategory of category.subCategories'>
                            <tr>
                                <td></td>
                                <td></td>
                                <td> +</td>
                                <td>{{subcategory.id}}</td>
                                <td>{{subcategory.name}}</td>
                            </tr>
                        </ng-container>
                    </ng-container>
                </ng-container>
            </ng-container>

        </ng-container>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

```
data = {
    policy: [
      {
        id: "a1",
        name: "policy 1.1",
        expand:false,
        categories: [
          {
            id: "c1",
            name: "category 1.1",
            expand:false,
            subCategories: [
              {
                id: "s1",
                name: "subCategory 1.1"
              },
              {
                id: "s2",
                name: "subCategory 1.2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "c2",
            name: "category 1.2",
            expand:false,
            subCategories: [
              {
                id: "s5",
                name: "subCategory 2.1"
              },
              {
                id: "s6",
                name: "subCategory 2.2"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      },
      {
        id: "a2",
        name: "policy 1.2",
        expand:false,
        categories: [
          {
            id: "c4",
            name: "category 1.1",
            expand:false,
            subCategories: [
              {
                id: "s13",
                name: "subCategory 1.1"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "c5",
            name: "category 1.2",
            expand:false,
            subCategories: [
              {
                id: "s17",
                name: "subCategory 2.1"
              },
              {
                id: "s18",
                name: "subCategory 2.2"
              }
            ]
          },
          {
            id: "c6",
            name: "category 1.3",
            expand:false,
            subCategories: [
              {
                id: "s21",
                name: "subCategory 3.1"
              }
            ]
          }
        ]
      }
    ]
  };
```

Comment: table row end is not correctly aligned... What I will do for<tr-row-end>

Comment: @AngelReji how you expect to align? add some images. But the alignment we can fix using colspan & CSS. should not be  a problem

Comment: Can I use this by the method which I used?? which means by using values from  three different method(dropdownData ,dropdownData1,dropdownData2). Instead of taking category from policy(policy.categories), I need to pass index and want to get value and wanna display variables below each policies.

Comment: You get me, what I am trying to convey??

Comment: Because I am using three different APIs... For getting the category, I have to pass policy as searchTerm , and likewise I have to pass category as searchTerm for getting subcategory..Thats why I used three methods....Instead of these three method I will have three getmethods

Comment: You can. after clicking policy set flag for loading and when data came, keep the data as an array (dropdownData1). then in ngFor you can filter the item which belong to the clicked policy.

Comment: need to close one row when other open.. for that what condition I have to write

Comment: Sent a stackblitz of what you have now

Comment: I have the same which you send me in stackblitz.... Eg: the policy contains 2 categories.... first  I open category1.1 ,then I open category 1.2 , now the category 1.1 should automatically close the expansion. At a time only one tr should expand

Comment: I am facing a problem in table, here is the link "https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60096967/angular-2-tree-table-using-api"... I dont need to close the row.. Can you please guide me??